# How to write script to accept licence agreement in bash script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# To install java and jre
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre

# END
```

While installing java and jre it will ask "Licence Agreement". How to write script to accept licence agreement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(partly from **[here](http://groups.google.com/group/ec2ubuntu/browse_thread/thread/7658c51eef40a4bb/3bd11b2e85853d86)** for background info)</sub>

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo "sun-java6-bin shared/accepted-sun-dlj-v1-1 boolean true" | 
      debconf-set-selections    
sudo -E apt-get install -y sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre
```

I highly recommend

- http://groups.google.com/group/ec2ubuntu

for this kind of question. PaaS computing is *the* place to look for automatic deployment scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f

apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
expect "[y/n]"
sleep 1
send "y\r"
```